# Retornar caracteres separados no mesmo resultado

Tags: javascript, regex

É possível obter num mesmo *match* (de preferência o último) dois caracteres que estão em posições diferentes dentro da string?

Por exemplo:

> "xxxx**a**12**b**" -> "ab"
>
> "xyxyyxxxxx**c**23**d**" -> "cd"

Sei onde os caracteres estão em relação ao final da string. Usando a regex `/(.)..(.)$/` obtenho os dois separados. Gostaria de retorná-los no mesmo resultado.

Comment: Usando só regex não estou a ver como capturar somente partes... podes explicar em que contexto vais precisar disso?

Comment: @Sergio preciso de uma forma genérica de extrair uma substring a partir de uma string, dependendo das configurações da aplicação. Pode ser o último caracter, algum no meio, ou neste caso, uma combinação de um caracter no meio e no final. Utilizando regex seria possível apenas trocar a regex aplicada, mantendo o restante do fluxo de execução igual.

Comment: Em que linguagem vais tratar essa string?

Comment: @Sergio Javascript

Comment: Achas que isto funciona no teu caso? -> https://jsfiddle.net/hesLqfoL/

Comment: Acho que a solução é fazer um join dos grupos capturados, a partir do segundo, mais ou menos como você fez. Assim funcionaria para `/(.)..(.)$/`, `/(.)$/` e outros. Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca uma resposta com essa ideia, pode ser útil a outros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente não é possível retornar num mesmo resultado. No meu caso a solução é concatenar os *matches* a partir do segundo. Dessa forma funciona para uma regex que retorna 1, 2 ou mais resultados.

Para o exemplo da pergunta (em JS):

```
r = /(.)..(.)$/;
s1 = "xxxxa12b";
m = r.exec(a); // ["a12b", "a", "b"]
s2 = m.slice(1).join(""); // "ab"
```